# Ruby: Elegant way to substitute captured part of string

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to do a string substitution where if I find a string between two terms I replace it, so when I have a string like:

```
"123 pre 456 post"
```

I can get:

```
"123 pre 789 post"
```

I can do this by doing something like:

```
string.sub(/(pre\s+)\S+(\s+post)/, "\\1789\\2")
```

However, I'd like to avoid using the two captures if possible. In fact, I'd like to use a regular expression like this instead: `/pre\s+(\S+)\s+post/` and get the range of the capture and then replace it. Is there a way to do that (using the standard Ruby libraries)?

Comment: What about look-ahead and look behind pattern?

Comment: @halfelf I'm not familiar with that pattern, please say more.

Comment: @ThomasW xdazz's answer is the look-ahead and look-behind patterns. Unfortunately they don't work in Ruby 1.8.7 (I'm not aware which version are you using).

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 at the time being, but if an elegant solution to this problem could be found using a newer version I might be compelled to switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]=` operator does this, although it modifies the string in place

```
s = "123 pre 456 post"
s[/pre\s+(\S+)\s+post/] = '789'
```

replaces the entire rexep match, and

```
s = "123 pre 456 post"
s[/pre\s+(\S+)\s+post/, 1] = '789'
```

replaces the specified capture groups (you can do this with named capture groups too).

Should work on 1.8.7 (although no named capture groups there I think) and 1.9

Comment: Thanks. Since this works with Ruby 1.8.7 I'm going to go with it as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could do like this:

```
"123 pre 456 post".sub(/(?<=pre)\s+\S+\s+(?=post)/, ' 789 ')
```

Comment: I'd include the `\s+` in the `pre` and `post` groups, only to approach to the OP's problem (maybe he wants to maintain the number of spaces).